# I wanna learn to make video games

Tags: c++, c#

Sry if it is a wrong place, but i need help about starting to learn making video games, because it's my big wish. So, i need some advices what should i start c++ or c#, unreal or unity. Honestly, unreal is a way better for me, but a lot of people saying me that c++ is also a way harder then c#, you should use c# first etc. Now, just give me some advices, your experience maybe, do i need some requirements, because i'm ready to learn, and need right thing. And i have some experience in web development, but that doesn't matter here.

Comment: This question needs to be closed as off-topic. I can't cast close votes though.

Comment: Consider going to some university and start doing a PhD about computer games. You'll learn how to make them. See also [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/) and contact me by email to `basile@starynkevitch.net` (home) or `basile.starynkevitch@cea.fr` (office, at https://www-list.cea.fr/ ....) if interested

Answer (score 1):

Games are in 2 parts the game content and the engine.
The engine handles all the hard work of physics and graphics.

If you use a game engine like unity you can spend most of your time building your game, and not construction under the hood.  In which case your going to need more 3D modelling skills than programming.

Even if you do build your own engine, which I don't recommend as its years worth of effort.

Even then you still need the 3d models, 1000's of them.  Cups, tables, chairs, guns, and etc all require modelling.

Find a game engine, and then find out what language it was written in, and that is the language you will need to learn.

Although I don't have an experience writing games, I play them all the time, and know how they work generally speaking.

Answer (score 1):

### **Hello Saha!**

> This is all based on my experience up to now. I did make some small game-dev projects prior to going more in-depth with functional programming and I seriously feel way more capable now than ever before.

**first and foremost**, I'd like to redirect you to the [appropriate website](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) for game-dev-related questions.

**secondly**, I'd like to give you my humble opinion about game-dev as a beginner: *the language and the software aren't really important.*

I'd suggest you to learn programming like computer scientists do (in a functional-first approach as defined in the [IEEE-CS/ACM Computing Curricula 2001](https://www.acm.org/binaries/content/assets/education/curricula-recommendations/cc2001.pdf)), because I think that by learning the functional way first, you force yourself to focus on the act of abstracting and on the logics of problem solving, instead of getting lost in variable pointers, not righteously filled arrays, petty language-specific syntax problems, and so on. To further your study you should then study how basic memory structures work (linked lists, arrays, stacks, queues, matrices). Only after that, you should start studying what's related with game logics and mechanics.

After that, your knowledge can easily be transported into basically every language, be it C++ or C# or whatever.

I hope not to have been too generic in my answer and that it actually helps!

**Good luck!**

*Furan*